# Why cannot I assign a function pointer variable to point to a specific function. Error is below

Tags: c++, function-pointers, static-methods

I have the following error

> "Assigning to 'TreeLeaf(TreeLeaf::*)(TreeLeaf,TreeLeaf)' from incompatibale type 'TreeLeaf(TreeLeaf,TreeLeaf)'"

In my TreeLeaf.h I have the following code

```
class TreeLeaf
{
    public:
    void checkVaribleValue(string command);
    int number;
    bool isOperator = false;

    TreeLeaf (TreeLeaf::*operation)(TreeLeaf var1, TreeLeaf var2);


    static TreeLeaf add(TreeLeaf var1, TreeLeaf var2);
};
```

In my TreeLeaf.cpp I have the following code

```
#include "TreeLeaf.h"


void TreeLeaf::checkVaribleValue(string command)
{
    if(isdigit(command[0]) || (command[0] == '-' && isdigit(command[1])))
    {
        number = stoi(command);
    }
    else
    {
        switch(command[0])
        {
            case '+':
                isOperator = true;// will used to know that that it operates on other leafs.
                operation = add;
                break;
        }
    }
}

TreeLeaf TreeLeaf::add(TreeLeaf var1, TreeLeaf var2)
{
    //TODO check type for now just working with ints
    TreeLeaf result;

    result.number = var1.number + var2.number;
    return result;
}
```

I get the error when I try to assign operation to add(`operation = add;`).

I am using XCode 7.3.

Comment: This question is different because the return value is a class. I was not sure if that was a reason for the problem. The other question simply dealt with void return type.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Voting to reopen as the confusion here is that a static class member function is not the same as a member function. The dupe doesn't touch on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static member function is not the same as a member function.  A member funtion needs an instance of a class where a static member function does not so a static member function is just like a global function but it's name is scoped to the class.  If you want to store a pointer to `add` then you would have

```
TreeLeaf (*operation)(TreeLeaf,TreeLeaf);
```

and then

```
operation = add;
```

would be

```
operation = &TreeLeaf::add;
```

Comment: This took away the error! Looks like ill be able to use it now, thanks! Ill comment later if something pops up. I very much appreciate your help!